# scanning data into 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc, scanf

i tried to look up in forums but could not resolve this problem.
in trying to get from the user a string into 2d array (char***)

here my code

```
int i=0;
int j=0;

if(!(main=(char***)malloc(numWords*sizeof(char**))))
    exit(1);

if(!(main[i]=(char**)malloc((numDef+1)*sizeof(char*))))
    exit(1);

if(!(main[i][j]=(char*)malloc((80)*sizeof(char))))
    exit(1);

for (j=1; j<numDef; j++)
    {
        if(!(main[i][j]=(char*)malloc((200)*sizeof(char))))
            exit(1);
    }
printf ("please Enter word: \n");
scanf("%s",main[i][j]); // Here is the problem
printf("Word typed:%s\n", main[i][j]);
```

I cant print the word inserted to make sure it is really scanned into the array.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not reset the `j` value after having it used here:

```
for (j=1; j<numDef; j++)
```

It would address one entry too far into your `main` variable when you use it after that loop like so:

```
scanf("%s",main[i][j]); // Here is the problem
```

because `j` now `== numDef` and that is one too far.

(Note: do not name your variable like the `main()` function of a C program)

Comment: wow thank you! such a silly problem. i was sure it is something with 2d array / scanf/ pointer.